# What to do when a bootable USB stick doesn't work properly?

Tags: live-usb, usb-creator

Currently I have Ubuntu 11.10 as an OS and I want Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I made a bootable USB stick with the program *Startup disk creator*. Everything went well (I chose the language, and then I chose 'Install'), the purple screen with the title 'Ubuntu' came up and it started loading too.

After some time black screen came up with white letters. Last sentence was something like:

> Panic occurred, switching back to text.

I tried it several times, the same thing happens. I tried clicking on *Try Ubuntu from USB* too but it didn't work either.

Comment: i forgot to mention: i couldn't upgrade to ubuntu 12.04, i tried that a few times too. Is it possible that my computer isn't compatible with ubuntu 12.04 but fine with ubuntu 11.10? my laptop is a packard bell.

Answer (score 1):

When you've downloaded an `.iso` image for Ubuntu and written it to a USB flash drive, and then you successfully boot it but experience problems during installation, the first things you should always do (if you haven't already) are:

1. [MD5 test the `.iso` image.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) (It can be corrupted during download or afterwards.)
2. [Check the USB flash drive for defects.](http://zootlinux.blogspot.com/2010/05/check-disc-for-defects-in-ubuntu-1004.html) (It can be corrupted during write or afterwards, or you could have bad hardware.)

Both the above steps apply to:

- all versions of Ubuntu
- both CD/DVD/Bluray and USB media

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems before with defective USB keys. The best would be to download a new iso image from the Ubuntu site and use a different USB key.

Good luck!